# How to create docker image from jenkins running on docker

Tags: jenkins, docker

I wanted to practice CI/CD with docker. There are many discussion going on this topic. But I'm very new these technologies I would grateful if someone can help me

I created my jenkins server on docker using AWS Ec2 instance. I want to create my web application container from a jenkin job.

How do I do it ? If it is possible how do I deploy my new container ?

How do I practice CD for each build

Answer (score 1):

This (free) online tutorial from Katacoda walks you through: [Building Docker Images using Jenkins](https://www.katacoda.com/courses/jenkins/build-docker-images).

Comment: Katacode tutorial is not working as they expected. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I found a really nice solution in this [link](https://stelligent.com/2016/08/24/containerized-ci-solutions-in-aws-part-1-jenkins-in-ecs/) .

It provides a cloudformation stack for creating an ECS cluster running a jenkins master container that can run jenkins slave containers to run individual builds. I later used this [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/tehranian/dind-jenkins-slave/) as the slave image for my builds, as it container docker in docker (dind) and can build docker images of it's own and publish them to a repository.

For a more in-depth explanation of this architecture, you can look at the great series of blogs by riot games, starting [here](https://engineering.riotgames.com/news/putting-jenkins-docker-container).